# Nested while loop for promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have followed the post [Correct way to write loops for promise.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660096/correct-way-to-write-loops-for-promise) to create loops for promise successfully.

However, it seems that this method doesn't work with nested loop

The loop I want to simulate:

```
var c = 0;
while(c < 6) {
    console.log(c);
    var d = 100;
    while(d > 95) {
        console.log(d);
        d--;
    } 
    c++;
}
```

Promised **(note that I simplified the logic of promFunc() here, so do not assume it is useless)** :

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var promiseWhile = Promise.method(function(condition, action) {
    if (!condition()) return;
        return action().then(promiseWhile.bind(null, condition, action));
    }); 

var promFunc = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(); 
    }); 
};

var c = 0;
promiseWhile(function() {
    return c < 6;
}, function() {
    return promFunc()
        .then(function() {
            console.log(c);

            // nested
            var d = 100;
            promiseWhile(function() {
                return d > 95; 
            }, function() {
                return promFunc()
                    .then(function() {
                        console.log(d);
                        d--;
                    }); 
            })// .then(function(){c++}); I put increment here as well but no dice...

            c++;
        }); 
}).then(function() {
    console.log('done');   
});
```

Actual result:

```
0
100
1
99
100
2
98
99
100
3
97
98
99
100
4
96
97
98
99
100
5
96
97
98
99
100
96
97
98
99
96
97
98
96
97
done
96
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`promWhile` returns a promise for which the outer loop needs to wait. You did forget to `return` it, which made the `then()` result resolve immediately after the outer `promFunc()` did.

```
… function loopbody() {
    return promFunc()
    .then(function() {
        console.log(c);
        c++; // move to top (or in the `then` as below)
        …
        return promiseWhile(
//      ^^^^^^
        … ) // .then(function(){c++});
    }); 
} …
```

Comment: Thx a lot! As a starter of promise, I find it difficult to understand the intricacies in promise. Are there any good tutorials or books you would suggest to read deepen my understanding of promise?

Comment: Check https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/General-Promise-Resources. Of course you're also welcome to read the [great promise question here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/promise+javascript?sort=votes)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `Promise.resolve()` instead of your `promFunc()` It does the same thing.