# While loop using bluebird promises

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I am trying to implement a while loop using promises.

The method outlined here seems to work.
http://blog.victorquinn.com/javascript-promise-while-loop
it uses a function like this

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var promiseWhile = function(condition, action) {
    var resolver = Promise.defer();

    var loop = function() {
        if (!condition()) return resolver.resolve();
        return Promise.cast(action())
            .then(loop)
            .catch(resolver.reject);
    };

    process.nextTick(loop);

    return resolver.promise;
};
```

This seems to use anti-patterns and deprecated methods like cast and defer.

Does anyone know a better or more modern way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain in words what you're really trying to accomplish?  Remember that a busy-wait loop is a horrible thing in Javascript.  It makes a lot more sense to use some sort of event handler rather than repeatedly call something in a tight loop.  And, what does `action()` do?  Perhaps show an example of how you would use this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`cast` can be translated to `resolve`. `defer` should [indeed not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572).

You'd create your loop only by chaining and nesting `then` invocations onto an initial `Promise.resolve(undefined)`.

```
function promiseWhile(predicate, action, value) {
    return Promise.resolve(value).then(predicate).then(function(condition) {
        if (condition)
            return promiseWhile(predicate, action, action());
    });
}
```

Here, both `predicate` and `action` may return promises. For similar implementations also have a look at [Correct way to write loops for promise.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24660096/1048572) Closer to your original function would be

```
function promiseWhile(predicate, action) {
    function loop() {
        if (!predicate()) return;
        return Promise.resolve(action()).then(loop);
    }
    return Promise.resolve().then(loop);
}
```

Comment: you can change the `loop` function to accept a value and then resolve it when the predicate is false, just to get the last value returned by the `action` function.

Comment: @Sami: Yes, [the answer in the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24660323/1048572) does that for example. However I wanted to keep this answer close to the OPs function which always resolves to `undefined`

Comment: Can you show an example of your `promiseWhile` in action? Pretty confused over here on how to actually use it.

Comment: What is `value` in the first example?

Comment: @JakeWilson It's the initial value for your predicate to check You can omit.it when the test function doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi. Was your example comment removed? Could you add the example to the answer maybe?

Comment: @JakeWilson The previous comment was wrong so I deleted it.

Comment: `var i=0; promiseWhile(()=>i<10, ()=>{i++, return Promise.delay(20)})` (without a `value`) or `var i=0; promiseWhile(x=>x<10, ()=>Promise.delay(20, ++i), i)`

Comment: Your code definitely doesn't work. Your example has issues as well as your original code (`condition` vs `predicate`??) If you could post a working example on `codepen` or something that would help.

Comment: @JakeWilson `predicate` is the function, `condition` is the boolean it returned

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this implementation as its easier to simulate break and continue with it:

```
var Continue = {}; // empty object serves as unique value
var again = _ => Continue;

var repeat = fn => Promise.try(fn, again)
  .then(val => val === Continue && repeat(fn) || val);
```

Example 1: stops when either the source or the destination indicate an error

```
repeat(again => 
    source.read()
    .then(data => destination.write(data))
    .then(again)
```

Example 2: stop randomly if the coin flip given 90% probability results with a 0

```
var blah = repeat(again =>
    Promise.delay(1000)
    .then(_ => console.log("Hello"))
    .then(_ => flipCoin(0.9) && again() || "blah"));
```

Example 3: Loop with condition that returns the sum:

```
repeat(again => {
  if (sum < 100) 
    return fetchValue()
      .then(val => sum += val)
      .then(again));
  else return sum;
})
```

Comment: I'd probably use a `Symbol` for a unique value, but otherwise looks good :)

Comment: god thinking benji