# Plain JavaScript + bluebird promises asynchronous for/while loop WITHOUT USING NODE.JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, promise, bluebird

There seem to be many answers to questions on how to use bluebird promises to call asynchronous functions from a for / while loop, but as far as I can see, all require node.js to work (e.g. promise.method()  or process.nextTick() ; e.g. such as: [While loop using bluebird promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375100/while-loop-using-bluebird-promises)  ).  Is there any way to do this in plain js + blue bird? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Node is plain js. (Also, your link has no reference of node)

Comment: Sorry but I don't use node.js  - are you telling me that .method() and process.nextTick() are available as js functions outside of node.js?

Comment: I don't know what `promise.method()` is, or where you saw this. (also not in the link)

Comment: Thanks - as I don't use node.js I don't know either, but it is used in  Bergi's answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660096/correct-way-to-write-loops-for-promise?lq=1 - this is the most useful answer I have seen yet - but still in node.js ...

Comment: @user3306881: No, I did **not** use node js in my answer. My post only contains `db.getUser` and `logger.log` and the `console` object in the examples, not in the `promiseWhile` solution. Only the OP did use `process.nextTick` in his *question* - for no apparent reason.

Comment: And yes, [`Promise.method`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisemethodfunction-fn---function) is part of the Bluebird library, it is available everywhere with Bluebird and is not part of node js.

Comment: Thanks - I don't use logger.log and .method hung in just plain js + bluebird - the only solution I have so far that works in bare js + bluebird is the one marked as the answer to this question. But thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, once something is a promise returning function - you don't really care about the environment the library takes care of it for you:

```
Promise.delay(1000); // an example of an asynchronous function
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) on converting functions to promise returning ones.

Now, once you have that sort of function a loop becomes pretty trivial:

```
function whileLoop(condition, fn){
    return Promise.try(function loop(val){
          return Promise.resolve(condition()).then(function(res){
              if(!res) return val; // done
              return fn().then(loop); // keep on looping
          });
    });
}
```

Which would let you do something like:

```
var i = 0; 
whileLoop(function(){
   return i < 10; // can also return a promise for async here
}, function body(){
    console.log("In loop body");
    i++;
    return Promise.delay(1000);
}).then(function(){
    console.log("All done!");
});
```

To demonstrate this works in a browser - here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aszhoe3z/)

Comment: @user3306881 just added a jsfiddle so you can try it out in your browser.

Comment: I get Uncaught TypeError: Promise.try is not a functionwhileLoop @ promise loops v3.html:32initialize @ promise loops v3.html:17  - any ideas?

Comment: @user3306881 you've not included bluebird - include bluebird as a script.

Comment: sorry didn't see the link to the fiddle?

Comment: my head has: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/latest/bluebird.js"></script>
<script>
window.BluebirdPromise = window.Promise.noConflict();
console.log(BluebirdPromise);
</script>  i.e. not the same as loading with node.js

Comment: Show me the code - http://www.jsfiddle.net, If you're calling Bluebird BluebirdPromise instead of the standard `Promise` then you should change all the referneces to `Promise.x` to `BluebirdPromise.x` in your code - there really is no reason to use noConflict most of the time though.

Comment: thanks - it was this - http://jsfiddle.net/simpkin/1j08f3ps/  - I am a complete newcomer to promises and didn't pickup on the syntax requirement in their API

Comment: @ Ben - OK just deleting the noConflict was the key. Many thanks.