# How to use defer() the right way?

Tags: javascript, promise, deferred

How do I use defer correctly? I've got two functions here, in which one defer is used correctly? In which one it is used incorrectly? And why resp. why not?

First example:

```
getFoo1: function() {
  var dfd = $q.defer();

  db.allDocs({include_docs: true}, function(err, response) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      dfd.reject(err);
    } else {
      var qcs = [];
      for(var i=0; i < response.total_rows; i++) {
        if(response.rows[i].doc.type == 'bar') {

          var qc = {id: response.rows[i].doc._id,
            isFoo: true
          };

          oneFunction(qc)
          .then(anotherFunction(qc))
          .then(qcs.push(qc));
        }
      }
      dfd.resolve(qcs);
    }
  });
  return dfd.promise;
},
```

Second example:

```
getFoo2: function() {
  var dfd = $q.defer();

  db.allDocs({include_docs: true}, function(err, response) {
    if(err) {
      dfd.reject(err);
    } else {
      dfd.resolve(response);
    }
  });

  return dfd.promise
  .then(function(response) {
    var foo = [];
    for(var i=0; i < response.total_rows; i++) {
      if(response.rows[i].doc.type == 'bar') {
        var qc = {id: response.rows[i].doc._id,
          isFoo: true
        };

        return oneFunction(qc)
        .then(anotherFunction(qc))
        .then(foo.push(qc));
      }   
    }
  }, function(err){
     console.log(err);
  });
},
```

The `oneFunction` does nothing asynchronously.

The `anotherFunction` does something asynchronously (retrieving data from an external database).

EDIT: Thanks to @Bergi the correct function should look like this:

```
getFoo3: function() {
  var dfd = $q.defer();

  db.allDocs({include_docs: true}, function(err, response) {
    if(err) {
      dfd.reject(err);
    } else {
      dfd.resolve(response);
    }
  });

  return dfd.promise
  .then(function(response) {
    var foos = [];

  for (var i=0; i < response.total_rows; i++) {
    if (response.rows[i].doc.type == 'bar') {
      var qc = {id: response.rows[i].doc._id,
        isFoo: true
      };
      var foo = oneFunction(qc);
      foos.push(foo);
    }
  }

  var promises = foos.map(anotherFunction); // make a promise for each foo
  return $q.all(promises);

  }, function(err){
     console.log(err);
  });
},
```

Comment: to `then` you should pass reference to function, but instead you instant call function like `anotherFunction(qc)`. So seems in both it used incorrectly :-)

Comment: Could you elaborate on your comment, please? At which `then` part? How should the function looks like instead, @Grundy?

Comment: if you explain what you expected, i can try explain how it should. Anyway i mean `.then(anotherFunction(qc))` should be like `.then(function(){anotherFunction(qc)})` until `anotherFunction` not return function

Comment: How does `anotherFunction()` gets it's parameter `qc`, @Grundy?

Comment: it take by closure :-)

Comment: but here a ugly sample, because in js variable scope on function level, so always passed last value

Comment: so here seems more right: `.then((function(a){return function(){anotherFunction(a)}})(qc))` :-) or simple `.then(anotherFunction.bind(null, qc))`

Comment: what is `a`, @Grundy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82098/discussion-between-thadeuszlay-and-grundy).

Comment: Why it's not `.then(function() {return function(qc){anotherFunction(qc)}})`, @Grundy

Comment: Both examples are incorrect. You're using [tag:pouchdb] in your example, Pouch already returns promises - so the correct usage pattern would be to use the promises it returns and work with them and then wrap it in a `$q.when`. I can elaborate in chat.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Yeah, sure. :) Please elaborate that in chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used `$q.defer` correctly in the second example<sup>[1]</sup> - creating a promise for the response of the `db.allDocs` asynchronous call (and nothing else). Altough pochdb seems to already return promises, as @Benjamin mentions in the comments, so it's unnecessary (but not wrong).

The first example is just a mess, convoluting the construction of the promise with the error logging and that ominous loop.

<sub>1: Except for `dfd.promise()`, which is not a function but a property. Go for `dfd.promise.then(…)`</sub>.

---

However, that loop is a very different topic, and seems to be wrong in both snippets. Some points:

- In the second snippet, your `return` from the callback function in the body of the loop, right on the first iteration that fulfills the predicate.
- If `oneFunction(qc)` is not asynchronous, it doesn't need to (read: shouldn't) return a promise - or if it does not, that `.then(…)` call is wrong.
- `anotherFunction(qc)` seems to return a promise (it's asynchronous as you say). But you must not pass that promise to `.then()`, a callback function is expected there!
- Same thing for `foo.push(qc)` - it's not a callback function that you would pass to `.then()`.
- After all, you are doing something asynchronous *in that loop*. Here, [you have to use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30872003/1048572) `Promise.all` now!

If I had to bet, I'd say you need

```
.then(function(response) {
  var foos = [];
  for (var i=0; i < response.total_rows; i++) {
    if (response.rows[i].doc.type == 'bar') {
      var qc = {id: response.rows[i].doc._id,
        isFoo: true
      };
      var foo = oneFunction(qc);
      foos.push(foo);
    }
  }
  var promises = foos.map(anotherFunction); // make a promise for each foo
  return $q.all(promises);
})
```

Comment: response.rows can be `map`d since it's an array, other than that looks good :)

Comment: Yeah, `filter`ed and `map`d, but I wanted to stay close to the original code.

Comment: @thadeuszlay: No, for the predicate `response.rows[i].doc.type == 'bar'` a standard [Array `filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will suffice.