# action function in promise loop not working

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660096/correct-way-to-write-loops-for-promise) question on stackoverflow, I've tried to make the `promiseFor` method work without success. Since I don't have enough "reputation" to comment on that thread, here I am. This is the recursive loop:

```
var promiseFor = Promise.method(function(condition, action, value) {
  if (!condition(value)) return value;
  return action(value).then(promiseFor.bind(null, condition, action));
});
```

And this is how I've tested it:

```
promiseFor(function(arr){   //condition
  return arr.length < 3;
}, function(arr){           //action
  arr.push(arr.length+1);
  return arr;
}, [])                      //initial value
.done(function(arr){
  console.log(arr);
});
```

I was expecting to have an output of `[1,2,3]`. But instead I got a `TypeError: undefined is not a function` pointing to the line:

```
  return action(value).then(promiseFor.bind(null, condition, action));
```

This happens to be the line that I haven't fully understood. What exactly does `promiseFor.bind(null, condition, action)` do?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to kyrylkov I've changed the `action` to:

```
function(arr){
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    arr.push(arr.length + 1);
    resolve(arr);
  });
}
```

Working like a charm now.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Ah, I should have made that `Promise.resolve(action(value)).then(…)` - someone whose `action` doesn't return a promise would have to trip over that some day. You can fix that by doing `return Promise.resolve(arr);`. Or have a look at [this alternative pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29396005/1048572).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test, `action` (2nd argument in anonymous function wrapped in `Promise.method`) is a function that returns an array, not a promise:

```
function(arr){
  arr.push(arr.length+1);
  return arr;
}
```

As a result you get the error in call `action(value).then` because the array doesn't have `then` method.

Comment: Thank you, totally didn't hink of that. Changed it to return a `new Promise` and now it's behaving the way I expected.