# Bluebird: chain .then handlers in a loop

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, bluebird

***Question:*** How to chain `getNextPaymentPayload/makePayment/confirmPayment` into a loop? You always can check if any payments remains with `hasAnyPayments` method.

***Problem:*** You can't do payments in parallel. To make a payment you need to wait while the previous one will be completed.

***Example:***

```
SomeService
    //first payment
    .getNextPaymentPayload()
    .then(paymentPayload => this.makePayment(paymentPayload))
    .then(paymentResponse => this.confirmPayment)
    //second payment        
    .then(SomeService.getNextPaymentPayload())
    .then(paymentPayload => this.makePayment(paymentPayload))
    .then(paymentResponse => this.confirmPayment)
    //so on...
```

---

Comment: what does `hasAnyPayments` return?

Comment: `.then(getNextPaymentPayload)`?

Comment: @Alnitak `true` or `false`. If `false` - you should stop payments, if `yes` - you should make at least one more round of `getNextPaymentPayload/makePayment/confirmPayment`

Comment: @elclanrs you're right. Corrected

Comment: So `hasAnyPayments` is synchronous, or returns a promise that returns a boolean?

Comment: But you are calling the function now, that looks wrong. `.then` is a higher-order function, it expects a function. `.then` sequences things, so if `getNextPaymentPayload` returns a promise, `.then(getNextPaymentPayload)` should happen after the previous one in the chain.

Comment: Use a [recursive approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29396005/1048572)

Comment: You are looking for a QueueConsumer that performs each registered task sequentially... right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `hasAnyPayments` will return a Promise that eventually resolves to a boolean:

```
let doPayments = () => {
    return hasAnyPayments().then((hasAny) => {
        if (!hasAny) {   
            return Promise.resolve();        // all done
        } else {
            return SomeService.getNextPaymentPayload()
                      .then(paymentPayLoad => this.makePayment(paymentPayLoad))
                      .then(paymentResponse => this.confirmPayment(paymentResponse))
                      .then(doPayments);     // "recurse"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like the most straightforward answer

Comment: @bonebrigade I've been using code just like this myself, recently.  In my own code I want a 1 second delay between each recursion so I use: `return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)` instead of a straight `Promise.resolve()`.

Comment: You could use [`Promise#delay`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/delay.html) in Bluebird.

Comment: @sdgluck I don't actually use Bluebird - the answer above just uses standard Promises without any extensions.

Comment: You don't need `return Promise.resolve()`.  You can just do `return;` there.  No need to create that extra promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 because it's wrapped in a `.then()` that will convert the bare (undefined) return value into a resolved promise?  You're right that I do need a `return` on the first line, though.

Comment: @Alnitak - I wasn't sure if the first `return` was needed or not since arrow functions do sometimes return things automatically (haven't quite figured out all their rules for that).

Comment: @jfriend00 arrow functions only return automatically if they're a single expression without a `{ }` block.