# resolve values in a Promise While Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I found:
 [Correct way to write loops for promise.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660096/correct-way-to-write-loops-for-promise)
and [While loop using bluebird promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375100/while-loop-using-bluebird-promises)

However when I try to use these to loop a promise, the resolve value of that promise is not passed down the chain.

For example, the following code prints:

did it 1 times
did it 2 times
***undefined***    <-- this should be **hello world**

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var times = 0;

var do_it = function(o) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("did it %d times", ++times);
            resolve(o);
        }, 1000);
    });
}

var promiseWhile = Promise.method(function(condition, action) {
    if (!condition()) return;
    return action().then(promiseWhile.bind(null, condition, action));
});

var do_it_twice = function(o) {
    return promiseWhile(
        function() { return times < 2; },
        function() { return do_it(o);  }
    );
}

do_it_twice("hello world").then(function(o) {console.log(o)});
```

Comment: `if (!condition()) return;` - change that to `if (!condition()) return 'oops';` ... what happens now?

Comment: Thanks. That was it.

Comment: really? that doesn't solve the problem, that shows you what you are doing wrong!

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify returned value

```
var promiseWhile = Promise.method(function(condition, action, result) {
    if (!condition()) return result;
    return action().then(promiseWhile.bind(null, condition, action, result));
});

var do_it_twice = function(o) {
    return promiseWhile(
        function() { return times < 2; },
        function() { return do_it(o);  },
        o
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a problem similar to this problem and came across this question. I ended up using an asynchronous recursive function to loop the request until a condition was met. In my case I had to check the length of an array attribute of the response (it was scraped data and a script on the page would sometimes not load the data before sending a response). Here was my solution, which sends another request if the response contained no articles (it is vanilla ES6 and allows you to use any condition (I used out.data.length===0)):

```
export async function scrape () {
    let out =  await axios.get('/api/scrape');
    if(out.data.articles.length===0){
        return await scrape();
    }
    else return out;
}
```