# In JavaScript, how to implement a recursive `ancestors()` function when `parent()` returns a Promise

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, promise, parent-child

Say I have the following in `thing.js`:

```js
var db = require('my-database-module');

module.exports = class Thing() {
  constructor(id, parentId, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.parentId = parentId;
    this.name = name;
  }

  static find(id) {
    // NOTE: The following find() function returns a Promise.
    return db.collection('things').find(id);
  }

  parent() {
    return this.constructor.find(this.parentId);
  }
}
```

Normally finding Things would be accomplished with the following:

```js
var Thing = require('thing');

Thing.find(123).then(function(thing) {
  // Do something with `thing`
});
```

You'll notice that I'm wanting to implement a parent/child hierarchy. I would like to add an `ancestors` function that returns an array of ancestor `Thing` objects for a given instance of `Thing`:

```js
module.exports = class Thing() {

  // ...

  ancestors() {
    var a = []

    // Can't figure this out...

    return a;
  }
}
```

Because the `Thing#parent` function returns a Promise, I'm getting confused on how the `ancestors` function should work. It would need to recursively lookup successive parents of the `Thing` instance.

[I've seen](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-creating-sequences) the `Array.prototype.reduce` function can be used for chaining Promises, but I don't know the Promises to chain upfront since it needs to recursively look for the parent, grandparent, great grandparent, etc.

Any ideas on how to structure this function?

Comment: Have a look at [this example approach to implement a `while` loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29396005/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method `.parent()` returns a promise who's fulfilled value would be the parent and it returns `null` when there are no more parents, then you can write something like this:

```
ancestors() {
    var parents = [];

    function getNext(obj) {
        return obj.parent().then(function(parent) {
            if (!parent) {
                // if no more parents, then we must be done with the chain
                // so return the whole parent chain
                return parents;
            } else {
                // still got another parent, add to the array and keep going
                parents.push(parent);
                // returning another promise here chains it to the previous one
                return getNext(parent);
            }
        });
    }

    return getNext(this);
}

// usage
obj.ancestors().then(function(parents) {
    // access to the whole parents array here
});
```

Comment: Ask and ye shall receive. That's a beauty. Thanks, @jfriend00!