# Do something N times using Bluebird Promises

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I am trying the Promises everyone is so excited about. They're are supposed to reduce code complexity which is a feature I've yet to observe.

In my case, I have a function that returns Promise. The function invokes key up or down event on Android device over ADB. I call it like this:

```
press(B_KEY, 3000, client, device)
  .then(function(result) {console.log("Key press done.");});
```

I would like to perform this action (call the `press`) function) several times in sequence. I can do this manually:

```
press(B_KEY, 3000, client, device)
  .then(function(result) {return press(B_KEY, 3000, client, device);})
  .then(function(result) {return press(B_KEY, 3000, client, device);})
  .then(function(result) {return press(B_KEY, 3000, client, device);})
  // ad nauseam
```

I would like to have something like `for` loop. I tried to think of pseudocode to show you, but any ideas I have are really ugly.

How to make for loop with all it's features in Promises?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While loop using bluebird promises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375100/while-loop-using-bluebird-promises)

Comment: @mdickin I've read that question and few others. Just FYI, while lop and for loop are different things.

Comment: A `for` loop is just a subclass of `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve your goal you could use mapSeries() to iterate n times over an empty array:

```
    return Promise.mapSeries(new Array(4), function() {
        return press(B_KEY, 3000, client, device);
    });
```

For more info about mapSeries() see the [reference](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html)