# Promise looping over nested arrays

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm wrestling with nested promise loops and having trouble finding a working solution.

I looked around and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29396005/3560729

The promiseWhile function seems to have what I need but I'm having trouble getting the nesting to return to the outer loop

promiseWhile:

```
function promiseWhile(predicate, action) {
    function loop() {
    if (!predicate()) return;
        return Promise.resolve(action()).then(loop);
    }
    return Promise.resolve().then(loop);
}
```

Nested Loop:

```
    let outerArray = outerArrayOfObjects;
    let returnArray = [];
    let returnArrayIndex = 0;
    let outerIndex = 0;
    let outerLength = outerArray.length;
    let passObject = { }; 

    promiseWhile(function() {
        return outerIndex < outerLength;
    }, function() {
        let innerIndex = 0;
        let innerLength = outerArray[outerIndex].innerArray.length;

        passObject = {
            innerObject: outerArray[outerIndex].innerArray[innerIndex],
            returnArray: returnArray,
            returnArrayIndex: returnArrayIndex
        };
        promiseWhile(function() {
            return innerIndex < innerLength;
        }, function() {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                Promise.all([
                    promiseFunction1(innerObject),
                    promiseFunction2(innerObject),
                    promiseFunction3(innerObject),
                ])
                    .then(function (allMappings) {
                        passObject.returnArray[returnArrayIndex++] = {
                            "result1": allMappings[0],
                            "result2": allMappings[1],
                            "result3": allMappings[2]
                        }
                        offersIndex++;
                        return resolve(passObject)
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        offersIndex++;
                        return reject(err);
                    })
            })
        })
        outerIndex++;
      }).then(function() {
        return resolve(passObject);
      });
      })
      }
```

I think my main questions are:  Where do I process the results?  How should I pass the values such that the return array is built properly?

Comment: Could you maybe summarize what you're trying to accomplish more generally? It seems like you have an array of arrays, and you want to iterate through every item and call 3 async functions on each one, and then store the results of those 3 async calls in a new array (of arrays?)... is that what's happening here? Also: does the order of processing matter? And do you need to know when the entire process is complete?

Comment: I've got an object that contains an array of objects, one of which is an array that I then need to loop over and execute a bunch of promise functions on. I ended up going with a completely different approach using bluebird, I'll post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promiseWhile above is good for performing actions but not good for setting values in a nested loop and returning the results.

I ended up going with an approach using bluebird:

```
        var Promise = require('bluebird');
        let outerArray = object.outerArray;
        let returnArray = [];
        let returnIndex = 0;
        Promise.map(outerArray, function (outerArrayObject) {
            let innerArray = outerArrayObject.innerArray;
            let outerArrayValue = outerArrayObject.value;

            Promise.map(innerArray, function (innerArrayObject) {

                Promise.all([
                    PromiseFunction1(innerArrayObject),
                    PromiseFunction2(innerArrayObject),
                    PromiseFunction3(innerArrayObject),
                ])
                    .then(function (allResults) {
                        returnArray[returnIndex++] = {
                            "result1": allResults[0],
                            "result2": allResults[1],
                            "result3": allResults[2],
                            "result4": outerArrayValue,
                        }
                        return resolve(returnArray);
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    })
            })
        })
            .then(function () {
                    return resolve(returnArray)
                }
            ).catch(function(err){
                    return reject(err);
                }
            )
        }
```