# How to break out of a serial loop when using promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I've got a long text file that I loop through line by line to extract some event data and store it in a database.  The file periodically gets updated with new data at the top.  When that happens, I run through the file again extracting the new events, but I want to stop when I get to an event that's already in the database (the file is always ordered newest to oldest).

Using the `reduce()` approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24985483/4200446) to the question [Correct way to write loops for promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660096/correct-way-to-write-loops-for-promise), I've come up with this function to parse the file:

```
function parse(
    file)
{
    var lines = file.split("\n"),
        latestDate;

    return lines.reduce(function(promise, line) {
        return promise.then(function() {
            if (/* line matches date pattern */) {
                latestDate = line;
            } else if (/* line matches event pattern */) {
                return Event.createAsync(line, latestDate);
            }

            return promise;
        });
    }, Promise.resolve())
        .catch({ errorName: "uniqueViolated" }, 
            function() { /* ignore only the createAsync error */ });
}
```

The `createAsync()` database method returns a promise that's resolved when the event is saved.  It will throw an exception if the event already exists in the database, which stops the promise chain so the rest of the file isn't parsed.  That exception is caught and ignored by the `catch()` handler at the end of the function.  I'm using the Bluebird 3.0 promise library in Node.js.

This function does loop through each line serially and correctly stops when it hits an already saved event.  But I'm wondering if this is the best way to break out of a loop while dealing with promises.  Swallowing the thrown exception at the end of the function seems a bit kludgy.

Any suggestions for improving the loop handling are welcome.

### Solution?

Building on [jib's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33590119/4200446), and taking into account [Bergi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587861/how-to-break-out-of-a-serial-loop-when-using-promises?noredirect=1#comment54961425_33587861) that maybe I should've just tried his non-reduce answer to the question I linked to :), I came up with this solution:

```
function parse(
    file)
{
    var lines = file.split("\n"),
        latestDate;

    return promiseEach(lines, function(line) {
        if (/* line matches date pattern */) {
            latestDate = line;
        } else if (/* line matches event pattern */) {
            return Event.createAsync(line, latestDate)
                .catch({ errorType: "uniqueViolated" }, function() { return false; });
        }
    });
}
```

The loop recursion is moved into a generic function, `promiseEach()`, that loops over every item in an array.  If the iterator function returns a promise, the next item isn't processed until that promise resolves.  If the iterator returns `false`, then the loop ends, Lo-dash style:

```
function promiseEach(
    list,
    iterator,
    index)
{
    index = index || 0;

    if (list && index < list.length) {
        return Promise.resolve(iterator(list[index])).then(function(result) {
            if (result !== false) {
                return promiseEach(list, iterator, ++index);
            }
        });
    } else {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
}
```

I think that does what I want, but I'm wondering if there'll be call stack issues if I run it over a 4000-line file.

Comment: I would check for the specific error from `createAsync` by name, and rethrow the error in the `catch` if it is different. Swallowing all errors is bad.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the `.error()` to a `.catch()` using the new Bluebird 3.0 object predicate syntax, so it should only swallow the error thrown by `createAsync()`. My question is still whether relying on a thrown exception is a reasonable way to break out of the loop, or if there's a more canonical approach.

Comment: Throwing an exception (or returning a rejected promise) is not just reasonable but the *only* way to break out of a .then chain (not the loop that built it).

Comment: You might just try to use the non-`reduce` approach from the other answer to the question you linked :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have doesn't actually break out of a loop at all.

Every call to `Event.createAsync` returns successfully right away with a promise, which means you always reduce over the *entire* array.

The length of the promise-chain produced by this loop will therefore always be the total number of lines in the file, less the number of lines that fit neither the date nor event pattern in your particular logic.

It's the *asynchronous execution* of this promise-chain that's later terminated when an error is thrown because an event already exists in the database.

Your code works, but you said this was a long text file, so it might be inefficient, especially if breaking out early is the norm rather than the exception (which it sounds like from your description).

I would therefore consider a recursive approach instead:

```
function parse(file) {
  var latestDate;

  function recurse(lines, i) {
    if (i >= lines.length) return Promise.resolve();

    var line = lines[i];
    if (/* line matches date pattern */) {
      latestDate = line;
    } else if (/* line matches event pattern */) {
      return Event.createAsync(line, latestDate).then(() => recurse(lines, i + 1));
    }
    return recurse(lines, i + 1);
  }

  return recurse(file.split("\n"), 0);
}
```

The benefit of a recursive approach is that the promise chain is extended asynchronously, when `Event.createAsync` resolves, and only as needed. You can also merely stop calling `recurse` to stop, i.e. there's no need for `Event.createAsync` to throw an exception to break out.

**A way to visualize the difference** may be to compare it to laying down tracks for a train, where the track represents the promise-chain, and the train represents the execution of the asynchronous operations that are promised:

With `reduce`, you always lay down the entire track first before the train starts, regardless of how far the train ends up going down the track before an exception stops it. You eat the cost of laying down the entire track each time (it may not be much, but it can add up).

In the `recurse` example, you're laying down the next piece of track just-in-time in front of the moving train, like [Gromit in the finale of "The Wrong Trousers"](https://ntanya54.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/wallace.jpg), so no time is wasted laying tracks that wont be needed.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I fooled myself thinking it wasn't looping over every line by logging the line in the `return promise.then(...)` block. The lines stopped getting logged after the first exception was thrown. But putting the log call just before that block does show that `reduce()` loops over the entire file, as I should've expected.

Comment: Actually, you'll need a `.catch({ errorType: "uniqueViolated" }, function() {})` handler after the `Event.createAsync(...).then(...)` call to catch the exception that's thrown when the event's already in the database. Otherwise, the promise chain will break, yet we want to treat the non-uniqueness error as normal and to continue with the chain.

Comment: Sure, but it's not going to do any more lines regardless, right? So it'll work whether you catch it here or further out.

Comment: Right, but the `parse()` function should be self-contained, so I can do `parse(file).then(...)` without having to worry about catching the uniqueness exception outside of it.