# Break for loop inside then() of a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs

I'm having a weird situation where I want to break a for loop after I have received the result of an Rx Promise and done some checks. What I have is the following:

```
function getDrift(groups) {
    var drift = {};
    groups.forEach(function(group) {
        if(group.type === 'something') {
            for(var i = 0; i < group.entries.length; i++) {
                fetchEntry(group.entries[i].id)
                 .then(function(entry) {
                     if(entry.type === 'someType'){
                         drift[entry._id] = getCoordinates(entry);
                         // break;
                     }
                 });
            }
        }
    });
    return drift;
}
```

where `fetchEntry` is returning a Promise of a mongodb document based on an id. If the `if` check is satisfied, I want to break the loop on the current `group.entries` and continue on to the next group.

Is that possible?

Thanks

**EDIT**: As requested, the groups object looks like this:

```
[
    {
        type: 'writing',
        entries: [{id: "someId", name: "someName"}, {id: "someId2", name: "someName2"}]
    },
    {
        type: 'reading',
        entries: [{id: "someId3", name: "someName3"}, {id: "someId4", name: "someName4"}]
    }
]
```

**SOLUTION**: I ended up using @MikeC 's suggestion with recursion and a callback to return the needed value. Thank you all!

Comment: The problem you've got here is the request is (presumably) asynchronous, while the loop is synchronous. Thus, the former cannot break the latter as, by the time the callback fires, the loop has long finished.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587861/how-to-break-out-of-a-serial-loop-when-using-promises/33590119#33590119

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That isn't possible because Promises are asynchronous which means [`then` won't execute until all other synchronous code completes.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

If you don't want to process all of them based on some condition, I would suggest creating a function which you call if you want to continue.

```
(function process(index) {
  if (index >= group.entries.length) {
    return;
  }
  fetchEntry(group.entries[index])
    .then(function(entry) {
      if(entry.type === 'someType'){
        drift[entry._id] = getCoordinates(entry);
        // don't call the function again
      } else {
        process(index + 1);
      }
    });
})(0);
```

Comment: I want to break the `for` loop not the `forEach`.

Comment: @XeniaSis My mistake. Still, the second point prevents that from happening.

Comment: @XeniaSis There is a solution. I'm writing it now. Be up in a moment.

Comment: will test that and get back to you

Comment: how can I return the drift object from the initial function? Cause as I understand, the function will return before everything else is complete

Comment: @XeniaSis You can't. You'll have to devise a different way of using the `drift` value. Perhaps by passing in a callback to your original function which is called with the `drift` value.

Answer (score 4):

The function you pass to then() is not called inside the for loop. It is called (long) after the for loop has finished.  This is the essence of the asynchronous programming model.

You will need to reorganize your code so that you don't use a for loop.  Instead you need to initiate the next fetch within the callback, or don't initiate it as appropriate.

*PS. You can't return an object populated by the callbacks, either, for the same reason: your function will return the empty object /before/ the callbacks are called*

---

*Edit:* demonstration, but code untested:

```
function getDrift(groups) {
    var promise = ...;

    var drift = {};
    groups.forEach(function(group) {
        if(group.type === 'something') {
            var i = 0;

            var processEntry = (function(entry) {
                     if(entry.type === 'someType'){
                         drift[entry._id] = getCoordinates(entry);

                         // We are finished, so complete our promise with
                         // the collected data
                         promise.success(drift);
                         return;
                     }

                     // increment our position in the array
                     i += 1;

                     // check to see if we are at the end of the array
                     if (i >= group.entries.length)
                        { return; }

                     // now fetch the next entry from the array
                    fetchEntry(group.entries[i].id)
                            .then(processEntry);
                 });

            // fetch the first entry
            fetchEntry(group.entries[i].id)
                 .then(processEntry);

            } // end if

    }); // end forEach()

    return promise;
}
```

Comment: I figured that, but I'm not really sure how to do it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I updated my answer with some code, but it needs some finishing to fill in parts of the promise handling: create the promise, and pass it the data when successful.  It shows how you need to encapsulate the behaviour in a function and to proceed through the array asynchronously in the callback instead of synchronously in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible *without recursion*, but not particularly simple.

You can use a combination of :

- replacing the `forEach()` with `Array#map()` to map `groups` to an array of promises,
- replacing the original `for` loop with `Array#reduce()` to build a `.then()` chain, which is "breakable" by sending it down its error path.

Simplest thing by far is to stick with `drift` as an outer variable as per the code in the question. Delivering the data via the promise chain is also possible but the code would be more involved.

```
function getDrift(groups) {
    var drift = {};
    // Map groups to an array of promises.
    var promises = groups.map(function(group) {
        if(group.type === 'something') {
            // Here, replace the original `for` loop with `group.entries.reduce()` to build a .then() chain.
            return group.entries.reduce(function(p, e) {
                return p.then(function() {
                    return fetchEntry(e.id).then(function(entry) {
                        if(entry.type === 'someType') {
                            drift[entry._id] = getCoordinates(entry); // Yay!
                            throw false; // Throw almost anything here to skip the rest of the .then() chain.
                        } else {
                            return true; // Return almost anything here to carry on down the chain.
                        }
                    });
                });
            }, Promise.resolve()) // Resolved starter promise for the reduction.
            .catch(function() { // If there was a match, we end up on the error path, and need to convert to success.
                return true; // Return almost anything here.
            });
        } else {
            return true; // Return almost anything here to make a positive entry on the `promises` array.
        }
    });
    return Promise.all(promises) // Aggregate the promises.
    .then(function() {
        return drift; // and deliver the populated `drift` to the calling function
    });
}
```

As `getDrift()` returns a promise, `drift` only becomes available to the caller in a .then() callback :

```
getDrift(groups).then(function(drift) {
    //do something with drift
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> If the if check is satisfied, I want to break the loop on the current
>   group.entries and continue on to the next group.

If interpret Question correctly, try using `Promise.all()` , `Array.prototype.map()`

```js
function getDrift(groups) {
  var drift = {};
  var m = 0;
  return Promise.all(groups.map(function(p) {
    // if `p` contains `5` return `null`
    // else multiply item within `p` by `10`
    return p.indexOf(5) === -1 ? p.map(function(k) {
      drift[m] = k * 10;
      ++m
    }) : null
  })).then(function(n) {
    return drift
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })

}
// array containing `5` will not be processed
var res = getDrift([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

---

Applying pattern above to `js` at Question

```
function getDrift(groups) {
  var drift = {};
  return Promise.all(groups.map(function(group) {
    return group.type === "something" 
    ? Promise.all(group.entries.map(function(g, index) {
      return fetchEntry(g.id).then(function(entry) {
         if (entry.type === "someType") {
            drift[entry._id] = getCoordinates(entry);
            return Promise.reject(entry.type);
         }
      })
    })) 
    : null
  })).then(function() {
    return drift
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })

}
// array containing `5` will not be processed
var res = getDrift(groups)
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: This doesn't stop the looping as it's not possible since it's an asynchronous function.

Comment: @guest271314 I want to break the loop if the `if` is successful, not do nothing

Comment: @XeniaSis What is meaning of _"and continue on to the next group."_

Comment: @guest271314 I am looping over some groups if you see in the code (the 1st `forEach` not the for loop)

Comment: @XeniaSis Can include example of `groups` object at Question ?

Comment: @XeniaSis Can also include example of response returned from `fetchEntry` at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 this actually throws an error and returns an `undefined` drift object.

Comment: @XeniaSis _" this actually throws an error and returns an undefined drift object."_ Second approach was untested. If possible, can share which line throws error , what error is logged ?

Comment: the `Promise.reject(entry.type)`. it consoles the `entry.type`