# javascript es6 promise to call async actions in while loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have a function like:

```
function callApi(url){
    return fetch(url).then(response => {return response.json()}
       ).then(response => {return response})
}

function myFunction() {
    var status = null;
    while (status != "complete") {
        setTimeout(function(){
            callApi('myurl').then(response => {
               status = response.status
            }
         }, 5000)
    }
```

Here I simply want to check if I am getting desired status from the api call.

Untill I get desired status from the api call I want to check on every 5 seconds..

But this is not working.. 
I have googled but not understood the solution according to my need.
It would be very helpful if anyone could answer this.

I am new to javascript. I have looked somewhere about `es6` promise. 
It would be very great if someone could explain this ..

thank you

Comment: Have a look at [Correct way to write loops for promise](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24660096/1048572)

Comment: You can (and should) completely omit `.then(response => {return response})`, the behaviour won't change a bit

Answer (score 1):

Put this helper in all your scripts:

```
var wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

then never call `setTimeout` again (it has terrible error-handling characteristics).

Also, `while` is a synchronous construct, which wont work here. You could use asynchronous "recursion". Also, to sequence asynchronous operations, promises must be chained:

```
function myFunction() {
  return callApi('myurl').then(response =>
    response.status == "complete" ? response : wait(5000).then(() => myFunction()));
}
```

Comment: Or just `.then(myFunction)`

Answer (score 0):

The current code have some typos (missing closing braclets on the `then` and `myFunction`) and a big flaw.

`setTimeout` is not a blocking Function, so you are running in the `while` loop more times that you think.
you are creating a LOT of 'later function' that will execute after 5 sec'.

right now, the flow of your code do this..

1. WHILE ...
2. CREATE A FUNCTION, BUT DONT RUN IT NOW ...
3. RETURN TO THE WHILE ...

line 2 will run thousand of times even before the first 5 sec will pass..

Here is your code, without typos, but the main issue still remains.

```
function myFunction()
{
    var status = null;
    while (status != "complete")
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            callApi('myurl').then(response => { status = response.status }); //<-- missing ')'
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

as for the main problem, you should not write code that checks every X sec' if something happend, instead you shoud use the Promise API and add a function to the `done` event.
that way your desired code will run only when the previous code in the asyncronous function finnished.

Comment: can you give example using `Promise Api`