# YouTupe API V3, multiple youtube.playlistItems.list requests not in the same order

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the javascript youtube API v3 to request 3 different playlists within some videos data. It's successfully working, but the method `execute()` is requesting the video data out of the order that was called in the looping (refresh the [page](http://s.codepen.io/guilima/debug/MaopWB/bYrdyGbGaewA)). The code is pretty simple and can be debugged [here](http://codepen.io/guilima/pen/MaopWB), or if preferred here:

```
var playlistsID = [...]
for (var i = 0; i < playlistsID.length; i++) {
  function playlistItem() {
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
      part: 'snippet',
      playlistId: playlistsID[i],
      maxResults: 4
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
      if ('error' in response) {
        console.log(response.error.message);
      }
      else {
        for (var j = 0; j < response.items.length; j++) {
          showVideo(response.items[j]);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

function showVideo(response) {
  var videoThumb = response.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url,
      container = document.getElementById("video-container"),
      videoDiv = document.createElement("div"),
      image = document.createElement("img");
  image.setAttribute("src", videoThumb);
  container.appendChild(videoDiv);
  videoDiv.appendChild(image);
}
```

My theory is that the `execute()` method is requesting the informations async, but if this is correct, What should I do to set a order in the requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Javascript Promise](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises) to wait for asynchronous request to be performed and use [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) library to loop them in the right order from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24660323/2614364) :

```
var promiseFor = Promise.method(function(condition, action, value) {
  if (!condition(value)) return value;
  return action(value).then(promiseFor.bind(null, condition, action));
});

//Load and grant access to youtube api
function googleApiKey() {

  var apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
  gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
  gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {

    promiseFor(function(count) {
      return count < playlists.length;
    }, function(count) {
      return requestVideo(playlists[count])
        .then(function(response) {

          //show video
          for (var j = 0; j < response.items.length; j++) {
            showVideo(response.items[j]);
          }

          return ++count;
        }, function(error) {
          console.log(response.error.message);
        });
    }, 0).then(console.log.bind(console, 'all done'));
  });
}

function requestVideo(playlist) {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
      part: 'snippet',
      playlistId: playlist,
      maxResults: 4
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {

      if ('error' in response) {
        reject(Error(response.error.message));
      }
      else {
        resolve(response);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Don't forget to add [bluebird link](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bluebird)

You can find a Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bmartel/ts8vbuj2/4/)